# Answered my own question, now it's community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Answered my own question, now it's community wiki?!

Reference: [What speed is 'fast' and 'faster' in VLC?](https://superuser.com/q/546278)

What's going on here?

Comment: Note that I had left a comment asking you to post your answer below your question. I waited 43 hours before doing so myself.

Answer (score 4):

What happened was that you edited your question to include an answer. But answers belong underneath a question, not part of it.

As most users would have done, slhck♦ edited out the answer portion and posted it as an answer. Not wanting to accept any reputation on it, and that it was using text originally from the question, it was marked as community wiki.

In future, if you do find yourself coming back to one of your questions with a solution, you need to post that as an answer and not edit the body of the question.

Comment: Unfortunately your system prevented me from doing so. It gave me two days until I could answer it myself.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser95 it requires that you wait 2 days before _accepting_ your own answer, but you can _post_ your own answer right away.

Comment: Looks like it wasn't two days... `Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.`

Comment: Correct, the time is 8 hours if you're below a certain reputation level. If you want to post your own answer, feel free to do so and then flag mine for deletion (link here as well) @sta

Comment: Luckily all is right now and you've earned yourself some nice rep :-)

Comment: Yup, all is turning out well now :)